# How to remove an item from a List<Integer> that is inside an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView t;
    List<Integer> listA = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3);
    List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(0,2,4,6,8);
    List<Integer>[] listC = (List<Integer>[])new List[2];

    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    listC[0] = listA;
    listC[1] = listB;
    t.setText("Result: "+ listC[0].get(1)); //Result: 1
    listC[0].remove(0); //i get an error in this line
}
```

I am very confused as of why I don't get an error with: listC[0].get(1)
but something's wrong with: listC[0].remove(0);
Is there something wrong with my codes? Is there a more efficient way? Please help me! Thank you so much!

Comment: are u getting an exception or an error?

Comment: Please share stacktrace

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

this appears in the logcat

Comment: What are you doing at this line - List<Integer>[] listC = (List<Integer>[])new List[2]; ?

Comment: sorry i'm new in android. how do i share the stacktrace? where can i find it?

Comment: Like LogCat output. If you are using Eclipse IDE it should popup when you get any errors. Just copy and paste the whole thing it prints. This shows what went wrong and where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you will get `UnSupportedOperationException` as `Arrays.asList()` is retuning unmodifiable List. so change

```
List<Integer> listA = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3);
List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(0,2,4,6,8);
```

to

```
List<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3));
List<Integer> listB = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4, 6, 8));
```

Comment: Can't we modify the list returned by Arrays.asList method?

Comment: @Octopus `Arrays.asList()` returns a *fixed size* List. You can't add or remove elements

Answer (score 0):

From doc for Arrays.asList :

> List java.util.Arrays.asList(Integer... array)
>
> public static List asList (T... array) 
>   Added in API level 1
>   Returns a List of the objects in the specified array. The size of the List cannot be modified, i.e. adding and removing are unsupported, but the elements can be set. Setting an element modifies the underlying array.
>
> Parameters
>   array  the array.
>
> Returns
>   a List of the elements of the specified array.

You can not change the size of the list,it will be better to change

```
List<Integer> listA = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4, 6, 8);
```

TO

```
ArrayList<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3));
ArrayList<Integer> listB = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4, 6, 8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of arrays I would suggest to use 
    `List<List<Integer>> listC = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(2);` a much cleaner way of doing it.

you can do all your operations like as follows.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        List<Integer> listA = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> listB = Arrays.asList(0, 2, 4, 6, 8);
        List<List<Integer>> listC = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(2);
        listC.add(listA);
        listC.add(listB);
        System.out.println("Complete List : " + listC);
        System.out.println("First Element :" + listC.get(0));
        listC.remove(1);// removed 2nd element
        System.out.println("List After Removal : " + listC);
    }
```

Output:

```
Complete List : [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
First Element :[0, 1, 2, 3]
List After Removal : [[0, 1, 2, 3]]
```